# LaTeX distribution problem pdftex.fmt

Tags: 13.04, latex

I just installed the TexLive 2012 from the Ubuntu Repository. After installation, I try compiling  and it gives the following error:

```
Unable to find pdftex.fmt.
```

Please let me know what is the problem?

Now I uninstalled and purged the entire latex distro, and now it is leaving packages unconfigured.

What would be the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Have tou installed `pdftex` and `pdflatex`?

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install texlive-full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from various documentations I found on the net that Texlive 2012 assumes no previous installations of TexLive packages for Ubuntu. Thus it is imperative to completely remove TexLive from a system, before installing a fresh TexLive distro.

The instructions for completely removing / purging texlive are given [in this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu). Inspite of that my fresh installation was not working. Therefore I did the following, after completely following the instructions on the above link:

```
sudo apt-get purge tex-common
sudo apt-get install tex-common
```

and after this one can install TexLive again from the Ubuntu 13.04 distro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo texconfig rehash
```

which should gives

```
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Done.
```

<sup>Source:Lindqvist</sup>

Comment: Did that already. Incidentally, I actually did all that and then asked this question.